# How to configure botium for chat bot testing step by step?

Tags: testing, automation

I am not able to setup Botium in my laptop. Even i have downloaded the node.js in my laptop. i have searched many websites but there is no proper explanation to configure botium.

Comment: What is Botium? Is there any error message you can share to further explain your problem?

Comment: This question will probably be closed.  Please add more detail to you question and let us know what you have tried and what exactly the problem(s) you are having is/are. The way this question sits now it looks like you are looking for someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Botium process is basically:

### 1. Write a botium.json file

It contains the information how Botium can connect to your chatbot. For a Microsoft Bot Framework bot, this would look like this:

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "Directline3 Plugin Sample",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "directline3",
      "DIRECTLINE3_SECRET": "my-directline-secret",
      "DIRECTLINE3_WEBSOCKET": true,
      "DIRECTLINE3_POLLINGINTERVAL": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

### 2. Write Test Cases (convo files)

The test cases in Botium are usually plain text files (you can use Excel as well if you want), looking like this:

```
#me
hello bot!

#bot
Hello, meat bag! How can I help you ?
```

### 3. Run the Test Cases

For beginners, the Botium CLI is the best way to start. Just download it and run:

```
botium-cli run --config path/to/botium.json --convos path/to/convo_files
```